# Independence of $\sigma-$algebra with random variables

Tags: probability, measure-theory, independence

Apparently we can show that a $\sigma-$algebra $\Sigma$ is independent of $\sigma(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ if we can show that for any bounded continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and any $E\in\Sigma$ that

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\chi_E f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\right] = \mathbb{P}(E)\mathbb{E}\left[f(X_1,\dots,X_n)\right]$$

how does this work again, and what is the theorem called?

Comment: Very roughly speaking, the idea is that the law of a random variable $X$ is characterized by $P(X\in G)$ for $G\in \mathcal O$, the collection of open subsets. Since we can approximate $1_G$ by bounded continuous functions, the law of $X$ is in fact determined by $E f(X)$ for $f\in BC(\mathbb R)$. Here, it's the same idea.

Comment: I believe you can even take $f$ to be uniformly continuous and bounded, see for example the section on weak convergence in Bilingsley's Probability and Measure.